# Google App Engine conneced Android App Failure

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I trying to deploy an android application connected to GAE. I run the online tutorial on google, I used the right configuration (as they write on the tutorial) but I can't communicate the Android Virtual Device with the web application running locally. The Web application shows me a "Server Error 500" and the android application on AVD shows me a "Failure:Connect to /192.168.56.1:8888 timed out" error.

I m running Eclipse Indigo and the virtual android device is with Google API Level 10.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Appengine dev server by default only accepts connections on localhost address (`localhost` and `127.0.0.1`).

To make it accept connections on all ports add `-bindAddress  0.0.0.0` to dev server parameters in Eclipse.

Comment: where are those dev server parameters?